# how to close a file that is created by spire.xls

Tags: c#, spire.xls

I am converting a CSV Document to a PDF as shown in the code with Spire.XLS.
The problem is that the File is still open after creation and I can't delete it while the programm is running. So does anyone know how I can close this file without closing the hole programm?

```
//check if open = false
        if (IsFileinUse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PDF open btn_ConvertToPDF_Click");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PDF closed btn_ConvertToPDF_Click");
        }

        //code that creates the file but does not close it
        Workbook wb = new Workbook();
        wb.LoadFromFile(filename + ".csv", ",");
        wb.ConverterSetting.SheetFitToPage = true;
        Worksheet sheet = wb.Worksheets[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < sheet.Columns.Length; i++)
        {
            sheet.AutoFitColumn(i);
        }
        sheet.SaveToPdf(filename+".pdf");

        //check if open = true
        if (IsFileinUse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PDF open btn_ConvertToPDF_Click");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PDF closed btn_ConvertToPDF_Click");
        }
```

Comment: Does `Worksheet` or `Workbook` not support any kind of `Close` or `Dispose`?

Comment: @Lloyd if there would be something like this i can't fi´nd it :(

Comment: Is the [example code from the spire documentation](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Convert-Excel-to-PDF-Excel-to-PDF-in-C-VB.NET.html) working for you?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel yes seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: @MarkusDeibel No. That page is empty. When I try [a similar page](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Excel-Conversion/NET-Excel-New-method-of-Convert-Excel-to-PDF.html), it doesn't show how to close the workbook.